# Update/Reset column values (with "counter") for each subset of IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have a table (`order_items`) that looks like:

```
+----------+-------+
| id       | order |
|----------+-------|
| 6c1e1f12 |     4 |
|----------+-------|
| 6c1e1f12 |     7 |
|----------+-------|
| 6c1e1f12 |     2 |
|----------+-------|
| 6c1e1f12 |     3 |
|----------+-------|
| 6c1e1f12 |     6 |
|----------+-------|
| 5d9f1892 |     5 |
|----------+-------|
| 5d9f1892 |     1 |
+----------+-------+
```

What I'm trying to do is to: "reset" the `order` values, starting with zero (every time), for every group of existing `id` records. So the result should be like:

```
+----------+-------+
| id       | order |
|----------+-------|
| 6c1e1f12 |     0 |
|----------+-------|
| 6c1e1f12 |     1 |
|----------+-------|
| 6c1e1f12 |     2 |
|----------+-------|
| 6c1e1f12 |     3 |
|----------+-------|
| 6c1e1f12 |     4 |
|----------+-------|
| 5d9f1892 |     0 |
|----------+-------|
| 5d9f1892 |     1 |
+----------+-------+
```

I don't mind the actual order — or how the rows were ordered before, in the sense that if, for instance, the row that previously had `12` as `order` becomes the one with `0` after this...and sort of.

I have this query to return the values in the way I want:

```
SELECT IF(@prev != a.id, @curr := 0, @curr := @curr + 1) AS order, @prev := a.id AS item_id
FROM (SELECT id FROM order_items, (SELECT @curr := 0, @prev := '') b ORDER BY id) a;
```

...but the `UPDATE` query that I'm building just set every `order` value to `1` regardless :(

```
UPDATE order_items, (
  SELECT IF(@prev != a.id, @curr := 0, @curr := @curr + 1) AS order, @prev := a.id as item_id
  FROM (SELECT id FROM order_items, (SELECT @curr := 0, @prev := '') b ORDER BY id) a
) AS tmp
SET order_items.order = tmp.order
WHERE order_items.id = tmp.item_id;
```

[This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dbe19/1) is a SQL Fiddle with the initial schema and some data.

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word, rendering it a poor choice as a table/column identifier.

Comment: @Strawberry it's `rank` actually, I just use a different one once I was typing this one; the same for the IDs, they are UUIDs.

Comment: rank is better. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Reference Manual warns that behavior of user-defined variables is not guaranteed:

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. ...
>
> you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. ...
>
> the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

---

With that noted, it is true that we do observe consistent behavior with carefully constructed SQL statements.

I've used this type of pattern, using user-defined variables with MySQL 5.6 with success. (I expect that with future versions of MySQL, with improvements to the optimizer, this may not continue to work.

Given the objective of the current statement, I would tend to write it like this:

```
 UPDATE (
          SELECT @curr := IF(o.id <> @prev, 0, @curr + 1) AS order
               , @prev := o.id                            AS item_id
               , o.pk_col 
            FROM ( SELECT @curr := 0, @prev := '') i
           CROSS
            JOIN order_items o
           ORDER BY o.id
         ) s
    JOIN order_items t
      ON t.pk_col = s.pk_col
     SET t.order  = s.order
```

I haven't tested this particular statement, but this is the pattern I use.

Some suggestions:

Avoid the comma syntax for the join operation, use the `JOIN` keyword instead.

Make sure the `ORDER BY` applies to the `SELECT` that is doing the evaluation and assignment to user-defined variables.

Do the assignment to the udv outside of the `IF` (i want the expressions in the `IF` function to be evaluated *first*, and then I do the assignment.

Qualify *all* column references with table name or table alias.

As a style preference, I assign the alias `s` to the source (the derived table/inline view), and assign alias `t` to the target table (the table that I'm updating).

I test the inline view query separately to be sure it's returning the result I expect.

If this pattern stops working, if I can't get to work, then I'm prepared to adjust to using an intermediate temporary table to make sure the view query is materialized before the UPDATE.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS __tt_vq__ ;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE __tt_vq__ ( ... ) ;
```

execute the query with the user defined variables and materialize that

```
INSERT INTO __tt_vq__  SELECT s.* FROM ( view query ) s ;
```

then verify that the results are as I expect (get the manipulation of the user-defined variables done before I do an UPDATE)

```
UPDATE __tt_vq__ s
  JOIN target t 
    ON t.id = s.id
   SET t.col = s.val
;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE __tt_vq__ ;
```

---

This approach using user-defined variables is specific to MySQL. Other databases (such as SQL Server and Oracle) provide analytic functions e.g. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` or `DENSE_RANK()`. We use user-defined variables to emulate that functionality.

To do it old school, without user-defined variables, and without analytic functions, we would need a column (or some set of columns) that is guaranteed to be unique. Then we could do a semijoin operation and get a count of rows that are "less than" (before) the current row.  That is, we think of the "order" column representing the "number of rows before this one",  so the first row has 0 rows before it, the second row has 1 row before it, etc.

*** EDIT ***

With the SQLFiddle added to the question, we now see that the table `order_items` has an `item_id` column and an `id` column (and that the `order` column is actually named `rank`.

[SQL Fiddle demonstration here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9caf62/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9caf62/1)

```
 -- #####################################
 -- added 2017-11-03 20:18:17 spencer7593

 UPDATE (
          SELECT @curr := IF(o.item_id <> @prev, 0, @curr + 1) AS rank
               , @prev := o.item_id                            AS item_id
               , o.id                                          AS id
            FROM ( SELECT @curr := 0, @prev := '') i
           CROSS
            JOIN order_items o
           ORDER BY o.item_id, o.id
         ) s
    JOIN order_items t
      ON t.id    = s.id
     SET t.rank  = s.rank
```

Comment: Except of course you'd probably have a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks for the explanation. I added a SQL Fiddle link in the question itself. I ran the `UPDATE` you provided but it's acting pretty much as the other that I initially had — in the sense that it doesn't update the values correctly. I'll give it another try. Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like we are conflating **`id`** and **`item_id`** columns (shown in the SQLFiddle but not in the original question).   The inline view query needs to order on `item_id` so we get the matches... but it also needs to return the unique key for the row (`id`) which can be used to identify the row to update. Query in this answer is updated to do that; added as EDIT  to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: (... if we use the unique `id` column for the comparison of this row to the previous row, it's never going to be equal, we're going to get all zeros.  If we use the non-unique column `item_id` for the ordering/comparison this row to previous row, we are going to get 0, 1, 2 ... but we also need to return a unique identifier for the row (`id`) -- the PRIMARY KEY that Strawberry said we would have. We need that so we can update each row with its rank value.

Comment: Yeah...I just checked it and you nailed it. I didn't think about it initially, that's why I wasn't including it. I have more fields/columns, but they are not important. Thanks again!